# CustomMapper in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape-web

I need to create a graph where the edge width is based on one of the edge property values. By looking at https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/wiki/StyleObject, I see Cytoscape has a discreteMapper/passthroughMapper/continuousMapper but none of these let me access the edge properties. However, looking at the source code there's also a customMapper, which based on previous Cytoscape documentation(http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/documentation/mappers) would allow me to access the edge properties and return the width based on them. How do I do this? Inside the style object I tried:

```
...
width: { customMapper: { functionName: "widthMapper" } },
...
```

and

```
var widthMapper = function(data) 
{
    console.log(data);
};
```

before the initialization call. By setting a breakpoint to the function I see it never gets called. What am I doing wrong, do I need to add the mapper function somewhere in the Cytoscape object so it can see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right syntax was

```
...
width: { customMapper: widthMapper },
...
```